# Removing document.onfullscreenchange Fullscreen API

Tags: javascript, html5-fullscreen

I got a page where is checking if the user left the fullscreen. I want to delete/destroy this event watcher but could not find out how i can do this on the description
[API Description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API)
 Here is my code:

```
  //create black background and disable scrolling
  $rootScope.fullScreen = !$rootScope.fullScreen;

  //make div fullScreen (Browser Native)
  if($rootScope.fullScreen == true) {
    var videoWindow = document.getElementById("full-screen");
    if (videoWindow.requestFullscreen) {
      videoWindow.requestFullscreen();
    }

      //check if user has closed fullscreen
      document.onwebkitfullscreenchange = function ( event ) {
        if(!document.webkitFullscreenElement) {
          $rootScope.fullScreen = false;
          //REMOVE THE EVENTHANDLER - STOP WATCHING!
          ?????????

        }
      };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your intention on removing the event?

```
document.onwebkitfullscreenchange = null;
```

should work.

Comment: I want to remove it when the user closed the fullscreen window. There is no need to keep watching this event. It is part of a bigger angular app so I want to keep it clean. Your simple solution WORKED! Very simple! Thx!